# How to remove "clear-screen" symbol from command output?

Tags: bash, output, symbols

I connect via ssh to server and use the `ffprobe` command to get specific data about video and audio streams from a media file on putty window, but in the result output there is a symbol `clear-screen`, ( Ctrl+L, ^L ), and clear terminal screen.
If redirect output to a file, and open in `mcedit`, it looks like this:

```
TAG:handler_name=^LVideoHardler
```

Running through `xxd`, the line looks like:

```
00000000: 5441 473a 6861 6e64 6c65 725f 6e61 6d65  TAG:handler_name
00000010: 3d0c 5669 6465 6f48 616e 646c 6572 0a    =.VideoHandler.
```

Is there any way to escape or remove this character from the output? Or save the output to a file and remove it already from the file?

thx

Comment: You are right it is a symbol form-feed and `tr` solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Great; adding an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^L`, per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII, is a form-feed (this can also be validated because the xxd output contains `0c`, which in decimal is ASCII character 12). To remove it with `tr`, you'd use the ANSI C escape sequence, which is `\f`.

Thus:

```
ffprobe ... | tr -d '\f' >file
```

...should store content in your output file with the unwanted character removed.

Comment: Glad to help! If this fixes your problem, please consider clicking the checkbox next to the answer to mark the problem solved.